# How To Get Total Line Count From All Text Files In A Directory

Tags: windows, text, command-line, count

I have a directory with several hundred text files and I need a way to count the combined total number of lines of all the txt files. I'm using Windows and I thought it would be easy enough to find through the command prompt, but the following only returns the number of files:

```
C:\> dir /b c:\temp | find /c /v “~~~”
```

This is only an example, but it returned the number of files without "~~~" when I expected it to go through each file and count the total number of lines without ~~~. Any suggestions to get a total count would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET /a countfiles=0
SET /a countlines=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO (
 SET /a countfiles+=1
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('find /c /v "~~~" "%sourcedir%\%%a"') DO CALL :setcount %%c
)
SET cou

GOTO :EOF

:setcount
IF "%2" neq "" shift&GOTO setcount
SET /a countlines +=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

For each filename found in the directory, count a file, then deliver to the subroutine `setcount` the output of the `find` command, typically

```
---------- U:\SOURCEDIR\T W O\FILE4.TXT: 3
```

Since we want the last item in this string, we simply shift the parameter until the second does not exist, hence the first must be the linecount from `find`, so add it.

Comment: To count all lines in all files in a directory, add the `/s` flag to `dir` and remove the ```%sourcedir%\``` part from the `find` call

Comment: @DavisDude : Not quite. The `/s` option to `dir` will include subdirectories, so instead of counting lines in files in the target directory, it will count lines in files in the directory and all subdirectories - different thing entirely.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear from the comment, but I want it to include subdirectories